# Process annotations from java files without compiling

Tags: java, maven, annotations

First maven project contains the sources with annotated classes.

Second maven project contains the annotation processor (`javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`).

I would like second project, on compile time, to process the sources (annotated) of first project and do some stuff.

How should I approach it?

I am guessing  Annotation Processor is not the right choice as it required to be bounded to a compiler...

The other option is to scan all java files in first project, load them (with class.forname) and process the annotation.

Can you suggest something else?

Comment: Not sure how would it help in my case, where I use the Annotation Processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply the `-proc:only` command-line argument to avoid compilation -- no `.class` files will be output.

The [javac documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) says:

> **-proc: [none, only]**
>
> Controls whether annotation processing and compilation are done.
>   `-proc:none` means that compilation takes place without annotation processing. `-proc:only` means that only annotation processing is done,
>   without any subsequent compilation.

Comment: First, it's maven (But I can supply this parameter to maven compiler plugin) but the issue is that I need to work on sources from other project. AND I don't want to recompile those sources.

Comment: `proc:none` doesn't do compilation -- it does not create `.class` files.  If you mean something else by "compilation", it might help others to clarify the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Second maven project has java files that I DO want to compile AND I want to generate sources based on annotated java files in first maven project, those generated sources should be also compiled inside second project.